# I need to restart my PC if theres no network connection after about 1 minute

Tags: command-line, powershell, script, tasks

I manage a number of Microsoft teams rooms. They do a nightly reboot and sometimes they come up without network. The environment they are in is very locked down so no ICPM traffic is allowed. What Im hoping to do is create a script to run `ipconfig` delayed on start up and then trigger a reboot if the ethernet adaptor comes up as Media Disconnected. what would this look like?

FWIW, hese are physical machines. I’m needing help with how to layout the script and the parsing. I’m not very familiar with Powershell or CMD syntax

Comment: a scheduled task to run after start/login, which runs a script that sleeps for a minute, checks ethernet and reboots if disconnected?

Comment: Are these VMs or physical machines?

Comment: You should not need to reboot. Down the interface and bring it back up may suffice, or down it then toggle the device before trying to bring it back up. However, you should be investigating /why/ the network does not come back.

Comment: inb4 an infinite reboot loop while the internet connection is down

Comment: Esther thats exactly what im looking for, Nazard they are physical machines, Bib im willing to try that but I think its a windows glitch. It happens across multiple networks though. Gantendo Id rather have an infinite reboot loop on a network down scenario than randomly losing pcs to nightly reboots. Its a much less common issue to actually lose network in this scenario.

Comment: Have you tried the network troubleshooter?

Comment: I would suggest trying to track down why the network interface is not coming up and correct the problem at the source. Infinite reboot cycle is not a realistic solution. I would also ask why ICMP is blocked as this doesn't improve network security - sounds like a network admin blocking info without any real reasoning behind the decision.

Comment: SO after further investigation it appears this (intermittent) Issue is fairly documented in the special teams build of windows 10. It looks like its not a network issue on our end. Anyways this solution has now been implemented and is working beautifully. I will closely watch for a patch to be released or a fix to be found so I can decommission this fix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code should restart your computer if the interface set in variable $interfaceName is on state "Disconnected"

```
$interfaceName = "Ethernet"
$interfaceState = (Get-NetAdapter | ? { $_.Name -eq $interfaceName}).Status
if($interfaceState -eq "Disconnected"){
    Restart-Computer
}
```

In a first time, I advise you to test directly this code by shutting down your interface manually then run the code with powershell.

Then you can configure a scheduled task running this code periodically.

**Warning** : be sure to set a high enough frequency for the task in order to let the time to your interface to start after the reboot

Comment: Perhaps a bad idea to give them what they want when what they want is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is a short term fix to a long term problem it is meant to only utilized until the actual solution is found. This concept should stabilize many many systems.

Comment: @Gantendo I understand this point of view. Nevertheless, like the author said, I think a short term fix is better than no fix at all, especially when you have operational constraint.

Comment: Just to let you know this was super helpful in aiding me to figure out more about the actual problem we still haven't resolved the main fix but have narrowed the problem down substantially